# R: Create a matrix of vectors of length m of 1:n elements, with a max of p occurrences of each element & set p by memory limits?

Tags: r, algorithm, memory, permutation

How can I use R to

1. calculate the number of rows in, and
2. efficiently create a matrix of, permutations, such that

the rows that contain every permutation of elements `1:n` in a vector of length `m`, for `n < m`, where each element of `1:n` occurs at most `p` times. The order elements does matter.

Given this formula, how do I determine whether the resulting matrix is within R's vector and matrix size limits, and my own computer's ram limits, short of running it to see if it will crash?

Specifically, how can I calculate the largest `p` allowed, for a given `m`and `n`?

For example, with `m=20` and `n=11`, using `expand.grid()` without the `p` limit, the problem definitely crashes - I just got this message:

`"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 762939.5 Gb"`

I only have 22 GB of ram - 3 one-thousandths of a percent of the requirement, if I have my decimal point right.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show what you are doing with `expand.grid`? If you do something like `do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(1:3), 5))` the answer is trivial. The number of rows is 3^5.

Comment: Yes, I can calculate the rows for a permutation of n objects m times is to add the limit that each of the n objects occurs at most p times. Without this limit I can not create a matrix of permutations of 11 objects chosen 20 times, allowing repetition and treating order as relevant, because it is way to big. I am hoping that restricting it to the case where no element is allowed to occur more than three or four times will cut it down to manageable size, but with the restriction I am unsure how to calculate the number or rows or the amount of memory.

Comment: My code for the permutation of 11 objects 20 times is below, but had I not been half asleep at the time, I would have known this could never run before I hit the return key. Or, no, this is actually 20 object chosen 11 times.  perM <-expand.grid(j1=1:20, j2=1:20, j3=1:20, j4=1:20, j5=1:20, j6=1:20, j7=1:20, j8=1:20, j9=1:20, j10=1:20, j11=1:20)

Comment: Show how you are trying to implement `p` (is it deterministic or random?). If you use `expand.grid` you create all permutations and need the memory for that. No way around it. However, it is easy to do this with loops and if those are not fast enough for your needs, they can be translated into C (and implemented with Rcpp) easily.